# Protobuf member by member copy from java to protobuf class and vice versa

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a question regarding "**Protocol buffer generated java class**".
Is there is any way to customise it, so that I do not have to copy member by member for conversion from java object to protobuf object and vice-versa.

For Instance: 
I have java class:

```
class Dummy{
  int id;
}
```

I have protocol buffer (.proto) file:

```
message Dummy{
 required int id = 1;
}
```

Now, for converting the java object to the proto buf or vice versa ,I have to assign member by member to objects [java/protobuf].

In the above case for converting the java object [javaObj] to protobuf object [protoObj] :

```
 Dummy protoObj = null;
 Builder builder = ProtoDummy.Dummy.newBuilder();
 builder.setId(javaObj.getId());
 protoObj = builder.build();
```

Similarly, for coverting from protobuf to java object, I have to perform member by member copy.

Is there is a way to directly assign the object or faster way then the one i am using.